# Inet6Address valid for invalid IPv6 Address

Tags: java, ipv6

I'm using `java.net.Inet6Address` to validate if an input string is a valid **IPv6 address** or not.

Here is my code snippet:

```
public static boolean isValidIPv6ddress(String address) {
    if (address.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        Object res = InetAddress.getByName(address);
        return res instanceof Inet6Address;
    } catch (final UnknownHostException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above method returns `true` even for the following inputs which are **invalid**:

```
System.out.println(isValidIPv6ddress("2A00:17C8:50C:0000:0000:0000:0000:00001"));
System.out.println(isValidIPv6ddress("2A00:17C8:50C:0000:0000:00000000000000:0000:00001"));
System.out.println(isValidIPv6ddress("2A00:17C8:50C:00001235:0000:00000000000000:0000:00001"));
```

Does the API **ignore leading zeroes**? Or is there a **bug** in the API?

Comment: According to what specific rules are you considering those invalid?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, according to RFC 4291. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the most current RFCs regarding the valid text representations of IPv6 addresses, you have encountered a bug, or a poor interpretation of IPv6 address text representation. The most current RFC for IPv6 address architecture is [*RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291). That RFC has [Section 2.2. Text Representation of Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2) that says (note that the limit is four hexadecimal digits):

> 2.2. Text Representation of Addresses
>
> There are three conventional forms for representing IPv6 addresses as
> text strings:
>
> 1. The preferred form is x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x, where the 'x's are **one to
>    four hexadecimal digits** of the eight 16-bit pieces of the address.
>    Examples:
>
>    ABCD:EF01:2345:6789:ABCD:EF01:2345:6789
>
>    2001:DB8:0:0:8:800:200C:417A
>
>    Note that it is not necessary to write the leading zeros in an
>    individual field, but there must be at least one numeral in every
>    field (except for the case described in 2.).
> 2. Due to some methods of allocating certain styles of IPv6
>    addresses, it will be common for addresses to contain long strings
>    of zero bits. In order to make writing addresses containing zero
>    bits easier, a special syntax is available to compress the zeros.
>    The use of "::" indicates one or more groups of 16 bits of zeros.
>    The "::" can only appear once in an address. The "::" can also be
>    used to compress leading or trailing zeros in an address.
>
>    For example, the following addresses
>
>    2001:DB8:0:0:8:800:200C:417A   a unicast address
>    FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101           a multicast address
>    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1                the loopback address
>    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0                the unspecified address
>
>    may be represented as
>
>    2001:DB8::8:800:200C:417A      a unicast address
>    FF01::101                      a multicast address
>    ::1                            the loopback address
>    ::                             the unspecified address
> 3. An alternative form that is sometimes more convenient when dealing
>    with a mixed environment of IPv4 and IPv6 nodes is
>    x:x:x:x:x:x:d.d.d.d, where the 'x's are the hexadecimal values of
>    the six high-order 16-bit pieces of the address, and the 'd's are
>    the decimal values of the four low-order 8-bit pieces of the
>    address (standard IPv4 representation). Examples:
>
>    0:0:0:0:0:0:13.1.68.3
>    0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:129.144.52.38
>
>    or in compressed form:
>
>    ::13.1.68.3
>    ::FFFF:129.144.52.38

Since RFC 4291 demands that there be no more than four hexadecimal characters per 16-bit field, it would be incorrect to consider any IPv6 address text representation with more than four hexadecimal characters in a 16-bit field to be valid.

---

RFC 4291 was updated by [*RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952), which further limited a proper representation in Section [4.1. Handling Leading Zeros](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4.1) in a 16-Bit Field to no leading zeros:

> 4.1. Handling Leading Zeros in a 16-Bit Field
>
> Leading zeros MUST be suppressed. For example, 2001:0db8::0001 is
> not acceptable and must be represented as 2001:db8::1. A single 16-bit 0000 field MUST be represented as 0.

RFC 5952 Also requires the compressed format where more than one consecutive 16-bit field must be compressed to `::`:

> 4.2. "::" Usage
>
> 4.2.1. Shorten as Much as Possible
>
> The use of the symbol "::" MUST be used to its maximum capability.
> For example, 2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1 must be shortened to 2001:db8::2:1.
> Likewise, 2001:db8::0:1 is not acceptable, because the symbol "::"
> could have been used to produce a shorter representation 2001:db8::1.
>
> 4.2.2. Handling One 16-Bit 0 Field
>
> The symbol "::" MUST NOT be used to shorten just one 16-bit 0
> field. For example, the representation 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1 is
> correct, but 2001:db8::1:1:1:1:1 is not correct.
>
> 4.2.3. Choice in Placement of "::"
>
> When there is an alternative choice in the placement of a "::", the
> longest run of consecutive 16-bit 0 fields MUST be shortened (i.e.,
> the sequence with three consecutive zero fields is shortened in 2001:
> 0:0:1:0:0:0:1). When the length of the consecutive 16-bit 0 fields
> are equal (i.e., 2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1), the first sequence of zero
> bits MUST be shortened.  For example, 2001:db8::1:0:0:1 is correct
> representation.

Basically, RFC 5952 is also requiring you to accept any valid RFC 4291 format, but you should only output any RFC 5952 formatted IPv6 text representation:

> 4. A Recommendation for IPv6 Text Representation
>
>    A recommendation for a canonical text representation format of IPv6
>    addresses is presented in this section. The recommendation in this
>    document is one that complies fully with [RFC4291], is implemented by
>    various operating systems, and is human friendly. The recommendation
>    in this section SHOULD be followed by systems when generating an
>    address to be represented as text, but all implementations MUST
>    accept and be able to handle any legitimate [RFC4291] format. It is
>    advised that humans also follow these recommendations when spelling
>    an address.

Comment: Well, that's a detailed answer. Good job.

Comment: Thanks @ron-maupin for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I Checked the documentation of the class java.net.Inet6Address, It Says only the [rfc2373](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt) is considered. This means the API is outdated and must be upgraded to consider the latest recommendation of IETF for IPv6 Text Representation.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the source code, it looks like it breaks the string into characters, then for each it does a bit operation to add the bits to the final result and then shifts left 4 bits and continues until it either hits a : or the result goes over 0xFFFF.  (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/util/IPAddressUtil.java.html lines 170 through 180).  Since the characters are all zeroes, obviously it will never exceed 0xFFFF, so it never hits that limit.

I also read RFC2373 and said leading zeroes are optional, but it doesn't explicitly put a limit on how many are permissible.  I'd say it's a bug, but (IMHO) only for someone being pedantic.

Comment: If leading zeroes are legal why is it a bug?

Comment: RFC 2373 was obsoleted by RFC 3513, which was obsoleted by RFC 4291, which was updated by [RFC 5259, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952). Section [4.1. Handling Leading Zeros in a 16-Bit Field](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4.1) says, "_Leading zeros MUST be suppressed. For example, 2001:0db8::0001 is not acceptable and must be represented as 2001:db8::1. A single 16-bit 0000 field MUST be represented as 0._"

Comment: Apparently leading zeroes are no longer permitted, so it is indeed a bug.

Comment: I Checked the documentation of the class java.net.Inet6Address, It Says only the rfc2373 [link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt) is considered. This means the API is outdated and must be upgraded to consider the latest recommendation of IETF  for IPv6 Text Representation.