# Parse string to IPV6 issues

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ipv6

I built my own IPV6 address picker control in WPF, looks like:

[image]

When i paste a string, i do:

```
String clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clipboard))
{
   IPAddress ipAddress;
   if (IPAddress.TryParse(clipboard.Trim(), out ipAddress))
   {
      // It works
```

But when i try to paste that IP address:

```
0:0:0:0:0:ffff:7f00:1
```

It will parse successfully to:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1
// IPAddress.ToLongString() will give me:
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:127.0.0.1
```

if i change anything else manually after that, code crash because it cannot parse that IP address

I know the address is tagged with IsIPv4MappedToIPv6

How should i display that IP address with my picker control?

Comment: Open a cmd.exe and type >Ipconfig/all.  There is a IPV6 address in the results.  Use that string in your code.  I did and it worked.  The format was : "XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%X"

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847665/3745413) explains that RFC 5952 requires the elimination of leading zeros, and compressing the address as much as possible. There is a link to the RFC, which is actually pretty easy to read.